# AJAX rails update for geocoder distance instance variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-geocoder

I have an instance variable `@lat_lng` that I need to refresh every 3 seconds. I am trying to use a respond_to AJAX Request.

The Variable in `welcome/_info` partial

```
#distance
  =number_with_precision(event.distance_to(@lat_lng), precision: 2)
```

The user updates the latitude and longitude on a form which is then sent to a cookie. I then am splitting the cookie to grab the latitude and longitude for the geocoder `distance_to` request. This is in my `welcome_controller`

```
@lat_lng = cookies[:lat_lng] ? cookies[:lat_lng].split("|") : nil
```

I am then creating an AJAX request in my `application.js` file

```
var ajax_update_latlng = function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/welcome/refresh'
  })
}

$(function(){
  setInterval(ajax_update_latlng, 3000)
});
```

The `/welcome/refresh` is showing `GET http://localhost:3000/welcome/refresh 500 (Internal Server Error)`

The log file shows

```
Started GET "/welcome/refresh" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-07 15:09:51 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#refresh as */*
  Rendered welcome/_info.html.haml (11.3ms)
  Rendered welcome/refresh_latlng.js.haml (12.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

NameError - undefined local variable or method `event' for #<#<Class:0x007fdbeb4255d0>:0x007fdbeb430958>:
```

I do have a refresh action in my welcome controller

```
  def refresh
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action =>"refresh_latlng.js" }
    end
  end
```

This renders the javascript file `refresh_latlng.js` which is

```
$('#distance').html("#{escape_javascript(render 'welcome/info', data: @lat_lng)}");
```

I have no idea why it cannot find it and I also would rather it update the variable in my controller because I use that variable in another area as well.

*Removed `rake routes` due to it being irrelevant.*

it looks like it is removing my event variable when it is refreshing giving it the server error(500). Here is where the partial is being pulled from the welcome controller.

```
def index
    @events = Event.all
    @lat_lng = cookies[:lat_lng] ? cookies[:lat_lng].split("|") : nil
    @locations= Event.where( "start = ?", Date.today).all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@locations) do |location, marker|
      marker.lat location.latitude
      marker.lng location.longitude
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "info", :locals => { :event => location }) <--this is pulling the info partial
      marker.picture({
        "url" => "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png", 
        "width" => 32, 
        "height" => 37 
      })
    end
```

Full `_info` partial

```
.event-data{id: event.id}
  .row
    .small-3.columns.mright
      .avatar
        %img.avatar{:src => event.user.avatar(:thumb), class: 'th'}
    .small-6.columns.mleft.left-border
      .name
        %strong
          = event.user.name
      .address
        = event.address
      .times  
        = event.start.strftime('%I:%M')
        to
        = event.end.strftime('%I:%M') 

    .small-2.columns.left-border
      .distance
        =number_with_precision(event.distance_to(@lat_lng), precision: 2)
        %br
        miles away
```

Comment: run `rake routes` and post the results

Comment: Is your issue the 404 when trying to access `/welcome/refresh`?

Comment: updated `rake routes`

Comment: Still trying to get a grip on this AJAX stuff. But.. wouldnt "url: welcome/refresh" look for a view named "refresh" on your "welcome" folder?

Comment: I'm only accessing the welcome/refresh as an action not a view. I just added it in my routes and now I get `GET http://localhost:3000/welcome/refresh 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: The way that I understood this method to work is it is supposed to be `url: /controller_name/action`

Comment: You might check what request format you are actually getting, even though it should be javascript.

Comment: With the 500, what error is in the log file?

Comment: `Started GET "/welcome/refresh" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-07 15:09:51 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#refresh as */*
  Rendered welcome/_info.html.haml (11.3ms)
  Rendered welcome/refresh_latlng.js.haml (12.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

NameError - undefined local variable or method 'event' for #<#<Class:0x007fdbeb4255d0>:0x007fdbeb430958>:`

Comment: updated with log file info

Comment: edited with more relevant information. It looks like it is removing my event variable giving it that server error

Comment: Anyone? I still can't figure this out and I have been doing this for a week.